# Google Cloud SQL proxy couldn't find default credentials

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-sdk

I'm trying to run Google Cloud SQL proxy locally like this:

```
$ ./cloud_sql_proxy -instances project-name:region-name:instance-id tcp:3306
```

But it's returning

```
google: could not find default credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for mor information.
```

My Google Cloud SDK is already installed and logged in to Google.

How do I fix this?

Comment: got an example 4 u https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BBxNHjpys7A&t=33s

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Two problems may be generating your problem.

To find what is login, using:

```
gcloud auth login
```

### 1. You haven't application default credentials

If you have a recent version of gcloud you will get:

```
WARNING: `gcloud auth login` no longer writes application default credentials.
```

To make your local application use your credentials you need to do ([ref](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login)):

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

If you don't see this warning consider [updating gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/components/update), with:

```
gcloud components update
```

### 2. You haven't defined your project

After login, you should see:

```
Your current project is [project-id].
```

Once again two solutions:

#### a. Associate a project

If you are not seeing this, do ([ref](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set)):

```
gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID
```

#### b. Use global `--project` flag in the call

In your command associate a project:

```
.\cloud_sql_proxy -instances=project-id:region-name:instance-id=tcp:3306 --project=project-id
```

Answer (score 14):

Google application default credentials are managed separately from gcloud credentials.

Use

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

instead to setup your user credentials as application default. See [reference](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login) for more info.

Previously `gcloud auth login` did this, but with more recent Cloud SDK versions this is no longer the case.

Note that switching gcloud configuration or setting account will not update application default credentials. Only commands in `gcloud auth application-default` can be used to manage these.

Also to use service account as application default credential you can use it directly by downloading its json key from developer [console](https://console.cloud.google.com).

Comment: The thing still returns the same error. I tried both `gcloud auth application-default login` and using external service account json key.

Comment: By any chance you have `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable set? Also have your tried to use `-credential_file` parameter?

Comment: It looks like I must set the default project in gcloud to the one which my instance is in. Otherwise, it would just return the error.

Answer (score 0):

## If you're in a CI/CD environment without access to a browser:

#### or if you simply want to automate the process.

Instead of running `gcloud auth application-default login` you need to expose the location of your service account json file using the variable `$GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`

e.g. `echo "export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=${TF_VAR_gcp_service_account_file_loc}" >> $BASH_ENV` (if you need to move env vars between steps/jobs). `$BASH_ENV` is a special property exposed by CircleCI, if you use a different CI/CD tool you will need to find the location of the bash profile.

or simply `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=[path-to-service-account-json-file]` for use within the same step

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario using cloud_sql_proxy, the approach is to use GCP-GSA (service accounts),
download cloud sql proxy :

```
wget https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 -O cloud_sql_proxy

chmod +x cloud_sql_proxy
```

create a proxy user :

```
gcloud iam service-accounts create proxy-user --display-name "proxy-user"

gcloud iam service-accounts list
```

[SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL] is the email on sql instance details .

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding [PROJECT_ID] --member \
serviceAccount:[SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL] --role roles/cloudsql.client

gcloud iam service-accounts keys create key.json --iam-account [SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL]


gcloud sql instances describe [INSTANCE_ID] | grep connectionName
```

CREATE A KEY JSON FILE FOR THE KUBE ENGINE

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=[INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]=tcp:3306 -credential_file=key.json &


kubectl create secret generic cloudsql-instance-credentials --from-file=credentials.json=key.json
```

Your deployment :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: <DEPLOYMENT-NAME>
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: <APPLICATION-NAME>
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: <APPLICATION-NAME>
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: <KSA-NAME>
      containers:
      - name: cloud-sql-proxy
        image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.17
        command:
          - "/cloud_sql_proxy"
          - "-instances=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>=tcp:<DB_PORT>"
        securityContext:
          runAsNonRoot: true
```